# Big query - Schedule Query on an external partitioned table with the keyword @run_date

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Because it is client data I've replace in this post the project name and the dataset name by ******)

I'm trying to create a new schedule query in BigQuery on Google cloud platform
The problem is I've got this error in the web Query editor

```
Cannot query over table '******.raw_bounce_rate' without a filter over column(s) 'dt' that can be used for partition elimination
```

The thing is I do filter on the column dt.

Here is the scheme of my external partitioned table

```
Tracking_Code   STRING  
Pages   STRING  NULLABLE    
Clicks_to_Page  INTEGER 
Path_Lengths    INTEGER 
Visit_Number    INTEGER 
Visitor_ID  STRING  
Mobile_Device_Type  STRING  
All_Visits  INTEGER 
dt  DATE
```

dt is the field of the partition and I selected the option "Require partition filter"

Here is the simplify sql of my query

```
WITH yesterday_raw_bounce_rate AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `******.raw_bounce_rate`
  WHERE dt = DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
),
entries_table as (
  SELECT dt,
    ifnull(Tracking_Code, "sans campagne") as tracking_code,
    ifnull(Pages, "page non trackée") as pages,
     Visitor_ID,
     Path_Lengths,
     Clicks_to_Page,
    SUM(all_visits) AS somme_visites
  FROM
    yesterday_raw_bounce_rate
  GROUP BY
    dt,
    Tracking_Code,
    Pages,
    Visitor_ID, 
    Path_Lengths,
    Clicks_to_Page
   HAVING
    somme_visites = 1 and Clicks_to_Page = 1
)
select * from entries_table
```

if  I remove the statement

```
Clicks_to_Page = 1
```

or if I replace the

```
DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

by a hard coded date

the query is accepted by Big Query, it does not make sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is an open issue, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157987385). It addresses the error regarding using @run_date filter in the filter of scheduled queries to partitioned tables with required filter. *The engineering team is currently working on it, although there is no ETA.*

In your scheduled query, you can use one of the two workarounds using @run_date.As follows:

**First option,**

```
DECLARE runDateVariable DATE DEFAULT @run_date;
#your code...
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(runDateVariable, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

**Second option,**

```
DECLARE runDateVariable DATE DEFAULT CAST(@run_date AS DATE);
#your code...
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(runDateVariable, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

In addition, you can also use [CURRENT_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#current_date) instead of @run_date, as shwon below:

```
DECLARE runDateVariable DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(); 
#your code...
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(runDateVariable, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

***UPDATE***

I have set up another scheduled query to run daily with a table partitioned by **DATE** from a field called `date_formatted` and the partition filter is required. Then I have set up a backfill, here, so I could see the result of the scheduled query for previous days. Below is the code I used:

```
DECLARE runDateVariable DATE DEFAULT @run_date;

SELECT @run_date as run_date, date_formatted, fullvisitorId FROM `project_id.dataset.table_name` WHERE date_formatted > DATE_SUB(runDateVariable, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: actually none of this works

The two firsts option still have errors "Undeclared query parameters"
and the last one does not work with backfill

Comment: You must configure a schedule query so the @run_date variable will be recognised. I have just set uo a scheduled query and ran a backfill and it worked. I have added the code I used in the ***UPDATE*** section of the answer.

Comment: Did you choose the option "Require partition filter" ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, my table's schema was: `date_formatted as DATE and fullvisitorId as INT64`. Did you try as the last comment I posted in the answer?

Comment: Hmm thanks but this solution isn't working for me.  I have 
DECLARE runTimeVariable TIMESTAMP DEFAULT @run_time;
...SELECT .. WHERE insert_timestamp > timestamp_sub(runTimeVariable, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
and I still see an error:
Cannot query over table ... without a filter over column(s) 'insert_timestamp' that can be used for partition elimination

Comment: Strangely though there is only an error when I have an AND after the condition I pasted

Comment: I posted the issue in full here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550228/in-bigquery-scheduled-sql-query-cant-where-on-a-partitioned-field-and-another-f